# 3D metrics visualization - Alternative to seerene / Software Diagnostics Efficiency Platform

Tags: windows, data-visualization, 3d

[seerene](https://www.seerene.com/) (formerly "Efficiency Platform" by Software Diagnostics) is a tool that

- calculates metrics from source code
- displays 3 metrics at a time in a 3D view (area, height, color)

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Efficiency Platform screenshot]

I'm looking for a tool that does the latter only (visualization).

The tool would need to

- take the input in a well-defined format (CSV, XML or similar, I don't really care), ideally 4 columns + header. The 4 columns are name of the item (e.g. class/file name) plus 3 metrics (e.g. lines of code, complexity, number of developers).
- convert those numbers into 3D boxes, where the area is calculated according the [squarified tree algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping)
- be able to switch axes
- provide some 3D navigation

The tool

- needs to run on Windows 7 SP1 x64 (or later if possible)
- can be commercial, if so, it shall cost less than 500 €
- must have a trial version for free ("Efficiency Platform" didn't have that. Getting a trial was possible for ~4k€, which was simply too expensive)

I have tried:

- using [Famix Generator](http://www.sharpmetrics.net/index.php/famix-generator) to create a Moose model and then convert that into 3D with [CodeCity](https://wettel.github.io/codecity.html). Unfortunately this already fails on a simple Hello World program with the error message

  > Cause of Dump: Unhandled exception: Import error: unknwon EMOF class 'FAMIX.FileAnchor'
- [SharpMetrics Workbench](http://www.sharpmetrics.net/index.php/communityedition) Community Edition, but it's for C# only and I'm looking for a more generic solution

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [python](http://python.org) and it's many visualisation libraries like [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/) or [VPython](http://vpython.org/).

- Input *- Python comes with good csv & xml parsing libraries*
- Squarify *- There is an implementation of the algorithm [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/squarify)*

  - *This will lay out your areas and you can add whichever metric you choose as the height*
  - *I would suggest that you will need to start out with the lowest level of your structure and squarify into each higher level grouping before squarifying the next higher level.*
- Able to select axes *Yes - You can select your own axes as needed*
- 3D Navigation - *All the above libraries provide some degree of navigation and the first two also provide, out of the box, a number of output options to save your data views.*
- Run on Windows 7/64 SP1 or later: *The above run on just about anything from a Raspberry Pi, through Windows XP..10, OS-X, Linux to supercomputer clusters.*
- Can be commercial but < 500€ - *all of the above are available for commercial use and at 0.00€ are definitely <500€*
- must have a trial version for free - *No trial version, just the full version **free**.*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Code Charta (https://github.com/MaibornWolff/codecharta) may be what you're looking for. It's free and open source and the analysis component is independent from the HTML5 visualisiation that takes a JSON input file and produces the navigatable 3D Tree Map.

Check out the online demo here https://maibornwolff.github.io/codecharta/visualization/app/

Full Disclosure: I am working for the company that open sourced the tool.